# upload values with webclient

Tags: vb.net, webclient

im trying to upload to this form with vb.net

```
<head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/login.css">
    </head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<form method="post" action="/addData">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <textarea name="data"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="go"/>
</form>
```

and here is the vb code

```
    Dim data2 As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
    data2.Add("id", TextBox1.Text)
    data2.Add("data", TextBox2.Text)
    data2.Add("add", "go")
    Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
    client.UploadValues("link", data2)
```

any idea what im doing wrong here?
im always getting error 404, but it's not right.
because i did simple check by showing msgbox displaying the page source.
and it worked

Comment: Is your `uriString` really empty?  Perhaps you could tell us what actually happens when you execute the code.

Comment: it's not empty.. this is just an example

Comment: The form sends its POST to `/addData`, which means you need to do so as well. If you're trying to POST to the page which's code you've shown above it won't work. The URL starts with a slash (`/`), meaning `addData` is located in the website's root directory. Thus you should send your POST to: `http://www.website.com/addData` (or `https://` if the website's using it).

Comment: thanks! it worked right away!!

Comment: Glad to hear! I posted it as an answer below so that the question can be marked as solved!

Answer (score 0):

We can't say much from that (at least I can't).

What you should do is inspect the POST request you send (via your regular browser) that way you will know what you need to send.

For example, here is how the POST request looks like for posting this answer.

```
qualityBanWarningShown=false&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fvb.net&post-text=We+can't+say+much+from+that+(at+least+I+can't).%0D%0A%0D%0AWhat+you+should+do+is+inspect+the+POST+request+you+send+(via+your+regular+browser)+that+way+you+will+know+what+you+need+to+send.&fkey=<something>&author=&i1l=<something>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form sends its POST to `/addData`, which means you need to do so as well. If you're trying to POST to the page which's code you've shown above it won't work.

The URL starts with a slash (`/`), meaning `addData` is located in the website's root directory. Thus you should send your POST to: `http://www.website.com/addData` (or `https://` depending on what the website is using).